# ros2 gripper change

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

i have the following request and i would like my robot arm from universal robots to change its gripper dynamically and place it in the appropriate position and attach the desired tool to the flange. Is this possible?
the urdf is static so the tools cannot be moved easily. i manage to attach the tool to the flange by transformations if it has “floating” as joint, but this comes with disadvantages, like the tool is constantly moving if it is defined with respect to the flange. if it is defined with respect to the world frame, the tool is missing when considering the trajectory planning, because it is still too world, even if it is visible on the flange. Is there a concrete solution idea on how to proceed? is that even possible?
i use ros2 humble and rivz2.